page does not show search country bar when using lib intl-tel-input
I'm using lib intl-tel-input version 18.2.1 for my web project. I saw in the lib docs it have searching country bar when user clicks the flag.
But in my project, search bar cannot display.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/18.2.1/css/intlTelInput.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/18.2.1/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/18.2.1/js/utils.js"></script>
<script>
    var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
    var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
        separateDialCode: false,
        countrySearch: true,
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/18.2.1/js/utils.js"
    });
</script>

this is my code
Thanks for your help

check the browser developer tools console for errors ... p.s. there is no PHP in your code, and not enough info to help

Getting a whole list of countries at least, with the code you have shown (and an input field added) - https://jsfiddle.net/bq72w65u/ It even modifies the input field, adding a placeholder. No proper formatting whatsoever though, so this appears to be missing necessary CSS?

@JaromandaX don't have any error in console of devtool

@C3roe I copied this code on the lib doc. at lib doc it show searching bar. but in my code. I cann't. I was create another HTML project using this lib. but the both is same, searching bar coundn't show

Not sure which exact documentation you are referring to, but https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input?tab=readme-ov-file#getting-started-using-a-cdn mentions including the stylesheet as the very first step.

@C3roe yes. I was read at https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input?tab=readme-ov-file#getting-started-using-a-cdn .  and I was add stylesheet. but issue dose not resolve

Do you have ONE input field with the id="phone" ? See my answer

@mplungjan yes I do. I have input field with id is phone. and look at your answer. But searching bar does not show. issue does not resolve

Right click the page, click inspect and  and find the input field and see if it is covered by some element with a higher z-index

@mplungjan I was create a HTML project using this lib for input phone number and choose country code. HTML project just has an element is input field phone  but the same issue. so I think it irrelevant z-index

As you can see in my answer, the code you posted works when there is an input field and a css file. So it must be something else in your "html project" whatever you mean by that, that hides your field

Your code is incomplete. You need an input field and a css file


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/18.2.1/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@24.4.0/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/18.2.1/js/utils.js"></script>
<input type="phone" id="phone" />
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
  var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
    separateDialCode: false,
    countrySearch: true,
    utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/18.2.1/js/utils.js"
  });
</script>



